# How to get started with Sharepoint 2010?

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I am ASP.NET developer with good amount of experience. I want to start with Sharepoint2010 development. Got SharePoint Foundation 2010 installed on my windows 7 machine.

Someone tell me where to start.

1 - What things should I focus on?

2 - Any good books/Tutorials?

3 - What are the additional things should know with SP2010 like InfoPath etc?

Anything you can share please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From all the SharePoint books i've read i would recommend [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470529423) book because of the very good balance of explaining new features, code examples, best practices and insights of the real experts.

SharePoint has become so big and complex over the years, i find it really difficult to choose 1 thing to focus on. Since you've got a background in ASP.NET you might find the InfoPath Services interesting. You will be suprised how fast and easy you're able to build forms, even without one single line of code ;-)

Here are some links to blogs/forums you might find interesting:

http://www.andrewconnell.com/blog/Default.aspx

http://community.bamboosolutions.com/blogs/

http://www.sharepointjoel.com/default.aspx

http://www.zimmergren.net/default.aspx (my alltime fav. swede!)

Also, if you did not know [codeplex.com](http://codeplex.com) yet, be sure to check it out aswell. There are many great projects to learn from.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to understand SharePoint is to start playing with it as an end user, working with lists, content types, document libraries, out-of-the-box webparts, etc. Check out all the features of the latest version. Then check out all the stuff that you can do through the central administration site. Only then move on the not-so-easy world of the SharePoint customizations through Visual Studio.

[This is my recommended book to get started with SP](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321718313)

There are a lot of technologies that integrate with SharePoint. It's a bigger world than what it seems from the outside. Just to name a few: InfoPath, WF, Dynamics CRM, PowerPivot, PerformancePoint, etc.

Hope this helps. Best of lucks, you'll need it :)